# Quartz.net does not fire jobs

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, quartz.net, azure-worker-roles

I created two Jobs in a worker role to send mass mailings, one scheduled to run five minutes after midnight, and another to run every hour to program new Jobs.

The expressions for the midnight Job CronTrigger is "0 5 0 **?" and for the hourly Job is "0 0 0/1 **?".

But I deploy the worker role in Azure and for an unknown reason the jobs are not executed before I had only the midnight job and worked perfect, but implements the hourly Job and everything stopped working

Here is the code:

```
IJobDetail recordatorioJob = null;

CronScheduleBuilder cronTrigger = CronScheduleBuilder.CronSchedule("0 5 0 * * ?")
      .InTimeZone(TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("SA Pacific Standard Time"));

ITrigger recordatorioTrigger = null;

CrearJobYTrigger(typeof(RecordatorioCitasJob), 
    "RecordatorioCitas", 
    "groupRecordatorios", 
    out recordatorioJob, 
    out recordatorioTrigger, 
    "Recordatorios citas a los pacientes", 
    cronTrigger);

_automatizador.ScheduleJob(recordatorioJob, recordatorioTrigger);
Trace.TraceInformation("Job Recordatorio programado");

IJobDetail actualizarJob = null;
ITrigger actualizarTrigger = null;
CronScheduleBuilder cronActualizar = CronScheduleBuilder
    .CronSchedule(string.Format("0 0 {0}/1 1/1 * ?", TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("SA Pacific Standard Time")).AddHours(1).Hour))
    .InTimeZone(TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("SA Pacific Standard Time"));

CrearJobYTrigger(typeof(ActualizarJob),
        "ActualizarDatos",
        "groupActualizar",
        out actualizarJob,
        out actualizarTrigger,
        "Actualiza el listado de jobs dentro del scheduler",
        cronActualizar);

_automatizador.ScheduleJob(actualizarJob, actualizarTrigger);

private void CrearJobYTrigger(Type tipoJob, string nombre, string grupo, out IJobDetail datosJob, out ITrigger datosTrigger, string descripcion = null, IScheduleBuilder schedule = null, IEnumerable<dynamic> dataMap = null)
    {
    JobBuilder jobBuilder = JobBuilder.Create(tipoJob)
        .WithIdentity(string.Format("{0}_Job", nombre), grupo);

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(descripcion))
    {
        jobBuilder = jobBuilder.WithDescription(descripcion);
    }
    if (dataMap != null)
    {
        JobDataMap jobMap = new JobDataMap();
        foreach (dynamic item in dataMap)
        {
        jobMap.Add(item.NombreParametro as string, item.DatosParametro);
        }
        jobBuilder.SetJobData(jobMap);
    }

    datosJob = jobBuilder.Build();

    TriggerBuilder triggerBuilder = TriggerBuilder.Create()
        .WithIdentity(string.Format("{0}_Trigger", nombre), grupo)
        .StartNow();

    if (schedule != null)
    {
        triggerBuilder = triggerBuilder.WithSchedule(schedule);
    }

    datosTrigger = triggerBuilder.Build();
}
```

Comment: Are you starting the Quartz scheduler: _automatizador..Start();

Comment: yep, the scheduler is started, I test the scheduler with a every 30 seconds Job, and it works